# Custom JWT authentication for API with IdentityServer4

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, identityserver4

I have a legacy ASP.Net MVC application with custom authentication (user/role/permission, etc) and a MySQL database. 
I'm now developing a simple ASP.NET Core 3.1 API that needs to connect to the same database for insertion of some data externally (that will later be used by the legacy application).
The API users will be added into the database from MVC system and the authentication needs to use JWT tokens.

I would rather not replicate all the authentication logic in the API (it's fairly complex) so I want to add a API end point to the MVC application to reuse the authentication logic already in place and return JWT/refresh token. This should be fairly simple.

My question is what's the best way of using this in the API? Should I simply use something like the snippet bellow and call the authentication end point in the MVC app from the authentication end point in API or is this a good candidate for using IdentityServer?

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's based on your application business logic. Using JWT is a simple way to provide a stateless authentication and authorization for your application. But if you are going to implement an application with multiple servers and clients It's better to use tools like IdentityServer that provides a solution for centralized identity management and single sign-on tools.

Comment: So in this case, given that I already have a legacy application that is doing the identity management (let's call it Application A) and a new API that needs identity management as well (let's call it Application B) and a number of clients that need to connect to this API how would you handle the identity management in the API?

Comment: It's been a while so I thought I share how implemented this. As Hadi mentioned IdentityServer would be useful for centralized identity management but in my case as the authentication logic was already implemented I couldn't change this so I scraped the idea. I tried both linking the API and existing app for authentication and replicating the logic in the API and in the end found the later simpler. So ended up using the same logic with JWT for the API.